# PHP - defining arrays with database values

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've been tasked to produce a web app that asks the user for an answer(option) to a specific question - performing different actions depending on the option chosen. Each question is stored in a database, along with each question's 7 options. For example, "what was your favourite food when you were younger?" could have the options: Cookies, cakes, pies, etc.

i've actually managed to write the script to define each value using 1D and 2D indexed arrays using mysqli_fetch_array. However, when I try to view the data stored in each question and answer array using for loops, I get a strange problem... All of the questions display, but only the first question's answers display.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("server","username","password","db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $arr = array();
    $ans = array();
    $i = 0;
    $c = 0;
    $q_sql = "SELECT Question FROM Question";

    $question = mysqli_query($con,$q_sql);

    while($q = mysqli_fetch_array($question)){
        $arr[$i] = $q['Question'];

        $a_sql = "SELECT Answer FROM Answer WHERE QuestionID = ".($i+1);
        $answer = mysqli_query($con,$a_sql);

        while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($answer)){
            $ans[$i][$c] = $a['Answer']; // array(0 => $i, 1 => $a);
            $c++;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){
            print "<br/>".$arr[$i];
            for ($c=0; $c < sizeof($ans[$i]); $c++){
                print "<br/>".$ans[2][$c];          
            }
        }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If any more info is needed, please ask. I have no idea why only one set of answers is displayed, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this statement, `print "<br/>".$ans[2][$c];`, it should be `print "<br/>".$ans[$i][$c];`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose each question has 5 answers. During the first iteration of the `Question` query, `$i = 0` and `$c` runs from `0` to `4`. During the second iteration, `$i = 1` and `$c` runs from `5` to `9`, so you filled in `$ans[1][5]`. But your loop that prints the answers expects the second index always to run from `0` to `sizeof($ans[$i])-1`.

You need to reset `$c` to `0` before the inner loop, not before the outer loop.

But there's also no reason to use multiple queries and nested loops, you should join them into a single query.

```
$sql = "SELECT q.ID, Question, Answer
        FROM Question AS q
        LEFT JOIN Answer AS a ON a.QuestionID = q.ID
        ORDER BY q.ID";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$last_qid = null;
$i = -1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['ID'] != $last_qid) {
        $i++;
        $arr[$i] = $row['Question'];
        $ans[$i] = array();
    }
    if ($row['Answer'] !== null) { // skip null value if there were no answers
        $ans[$i][] = $row['Answer'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there was something obvious that I missed!!